# I need Help on Android GooglemAp code using the supportMapfragment

Tags: java, android, xml

my codes are

`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1_layout);

    try {
        // Loading map
        //initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {

        //
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(7.0722388, 125.6125396)).zoom(12)
                .build();
        googleMap.setMapType(mapType);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 7.0861111;
        double longitude = 125.4866666;
        double latitude1 = 7.3142777;
        double longitude1 = 125.6693055;
        double latitude2 = 6.9973333;
        double longitude2 = 125.4896666;
        double latitude3 = 7.2653333;
        double longitude3 = 125.6656333;
        double latitude4 = 7.27905557;
        double longitude4 = 125.3088333;
        double latitude5 = 6.6912333;
        double longitude5 = 125.1862;
        double latitude6 = 7.0722388;
        double longitude6 = 125.6125396;
        double latitude7 = 7.1759166;
        double longitude7 = 125.6333;
        double latitude8 = 7.0601333;
        double longitude8 = 125.59775;
        double latitude9 = 7.0003333;
        double longitude9 = 125.4538;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("AWS03 - UPMin").snippet("Tugbok Dist., Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1))
                .title("AWS04 - DNSC").snippet("Panabo, Davao del Norte");
        MarkerOptions marker2 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2))
                .title("AWS07 - Unlad Kabayan")
                .snippet("Toril, Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker3 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude3, longitude3))
                .title("AWS09 - Lasang")
                .snippet("Lasang NHS, Lasang, Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker4 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude4, longitude4))
                .title("AWS0A - Marilog")
                .snippet("Marilog Dist., Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker5 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude5, longitude5))
                .title("AWS0B - NIA")
                .snippet("Kapoc, Matanao, Davao del Sur");
        MarkerOptions marker6 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude6, longitude6))
                .title("AWS0C - AdDU")
                .snippet("AdDU, Roxas Ave., Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker7 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude7, longitude7))
                .title("AWS11 - Mudiang")
                .snippet("Brgy. Mudiang, Davao City");
        MarkerOptions marker8 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude8, longitude8))
                .title("AWS12 - AdDU HS")
                .snippet("AdDU High School, Matina");
        MarkerOptions marker9 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude9, longitude9))
                .title("AWS14 - Catigan")
                .snippet("Catigan, Toril, Davao City");

        //

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker1);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker2);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker3);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker4);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker5);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker6);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker7);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker8);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker9);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        /*if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }*/
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

}
```

also i keep getting this error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
 can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

this is my LOG

```
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/liblog(1486): failed to call dumpstate
```

01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.thesis.awsapp/com.thesis.awsapp.Tab1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:138)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:676)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:348)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:141)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at com.thesis.awsapp.Tab1Activity.initilizeMap(Tab1Activity.java:43)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at com.thesis.awsapp.Tab1Activity.onResume(Tab1Activity.java:141)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
01-01 10:51:37.820: E/AndroidRuntime(9040):     ... 17 more
01-01 10:51:37.828: E/(1486): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
01-01 10:51:38.171: E/StatusBarPolicy(1539): ecio: 23
01-01 10:51:38.171: E/StatusBarPolicy(1539): iconLevel: 4

can anyone hELP ME PLEASE!!!

my manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.thesis.awsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Splash SCreen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- MAIN ACTIVTY -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <!-- About Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.about_layout" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Tab1 Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.tab1_layout" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Tab2 Activity -->
</application>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YourApiKey" />
```

Comment: read the stack trace it tells you the problem

Comment: `<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` missing this in the application tag of manifest

Comment: i already added that in my manifest

Comment: it keeps crashing in my device i am using samsung galaxy y

Comment: that activity is part of a tabhost does that do anything to create the error?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, it says what you need to do:

> 01-01 10:11:20.570: E/AndroidRuntime(8222): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following
>   declaration within the  element:      01-01
>   10:11:20.570: E/AndroidRuntime(8222):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
>   01-01 10:11:20.570: E/AndroidRuntime(8222):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown
>   Source) 01-01 10:11:20.570: E/AndroidRuntime(8222):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source) 0

Also, make sure you put the meta-data nodes within the  tag, not outside of it.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YourKeyHere" />


    <!-- Splash SCreen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- MAIN ACTIVTY -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <!-- About Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.about_layout" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Tab1 Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.tab1_layout" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Tab2 Activity -->
</application>
```

Comment: i have edited my log kindly look at what is wrong now.. 
i did what you told me concerning the manifest

Comment: it also shows this error
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3027105

Comment: then change it to 4242000

Comment: What error, you just said that it says the google play services version is out of date, I told you to change it.. Note that you have defined it in resoruces file so you have to change the referenced value. With android studio you can control+click to go straight to that and change it.

Comment: how do i change that? by the way?

how do i fix the error in the log above?

Comment: the error concerning the null exception in the log above?

Comment: please start thinking about the problem I'm not your personal assistant.